# Как ArrayList конвертировать в обычный array?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Мне нужно конвертировать:

```
 ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

в `int[] arr;`

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `list.toArray(...)`.

Comment: Кстати, Вы хотите преобразовать числа с плавающей точкой к целым числам. Как Вы это представляете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, так:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
Double[] array = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
```

Если хотите преобразовать затем в `int[] arr`, можно пройтись таким образом:

```
int[] arr = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int) array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

int[] ints = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).toArray();
```

только учти, что числа с плавающей точкой выкинут исключение.

Comment: возможно стоит уточнить что stream доступно только с java 8